# Need Regex to validate Numeric values and empty spaces

Tags: regex, django-rest-framework, python-3.8

I am using the below regex pattern to validate numerics and spaces

```
 "^[0-9\s]{1,50}"
```

Attaching sample payload which i am receiving

```
 {"numberval":""}
 {"numberval":" "}
 {"numberval":"10,11,12"}
```

I am using python re module and compile method to validate the regex.
can any one help me with regex which can validate both the inputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you consider valid whitespace only or comma separated numbers, you could use this regex pattern:

```
^(?:\s*|\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*)$
```

### Demo

This regex pattern says to match:

- `^` from the start of the value
- `(?:`

  - `\s*` either zero or more whitespace characters
  - `|` OR
  - `\d+` a number
  - `(?:,\s*\d+)*` followed by zero or more other comma separated numbers
- `)`
- `$` end of the value